# Using the keyboard to select a column does not work

Tags: macos, sublimetext3

According to [this documentation](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/reference/keyboard_shortcuts_osx.html), `⌃ + ⇧ + Up` can be used to select a column using the keyboard in sublime. However, on my mac, this just slowing animates all the open windows to a state where they are all visible. Is there a way to use this sublime functionality on a mac?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is due to <kbd>Ctrl+Up Arrow</kbd> being set up as the `Mission Control` shortcut (when <kbd>Shift</kbd> is included, the animation is slower). I believe that this is something that started happening circa Mountain Lion and the default binding in Sublime has not been changed.

One way around this is to go to `System Preferences > Mission Control` on your Mac and change the default key bindings for `Mission Control` and `Application windows` to be something different or turned off entirely (if you don't use that functionality).

If you actually *do* use that functionality, you would need to change the Sublime key binding to something different. The defaults are:

```
{ "keys": ["ctrl+shift+up"], "command": "select_lines", "args": {"forward": false} },
{ "keys": ["ctrl+shift+down"], "command": "select_lines", "args": {"forward": true} },
```

Select `Sublime Text > Preferences > Key Bindings - User` from the menu and copy the default values in,  then replace the keys used to be something more suitable for you.